# How to "animate" the adding of rows to a JTable

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, jtable

I want to display the JTable each time a row is added.
The code that i write below add a new row to table , then display the jtable for 2 seconds ,then add another row , then display the table. But the jtable is not displaying ,
It only display after adding all rows

```
        Vector<Object> rowVector = null;
        while(rs.next()){
            rowVector = new Vector<Object>();
            for(int i=1;i<=columnCount;i++){
                rowVector.add(rs.getString(i));
                //System.out.print(rs.getString(i));
            }

            System.out.println(rowVector.toString());
            //data.add(rowVector);
            model.addRow(rowVector);
            JTable table1 = new JTable(model);
            JTableHeader header1 = table1.getTableHeader();
            table1.setEnabled(false);
            header1.setResizingAllowed(false);
            header1.setReorderingAllowed(false);
            header1.setForeground(Color.white);
            header1.setBackground(Color.black); 
            jpanedisplay.setViewportView(table1);           
            jpanedisplay.getViewport().setBackground(Color.white);
            jpanedisplay.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black));
            Thread.sleep(3000);

        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're creating a new `JTable` in each iteration, you don't need to do that. Add the model to the table before the loop. And just add rows to the model in the loop

```
DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(columnNames, 0);
JTable table = new JTable(model);

table.setEnabled(false);
JTableHeader header1 = table.getTableHeader();
header1.setResizingAllowed(false);
header1.setReorderingAllowed(false);
header1.setForeground(Color.white);
header1.setBackground(Color.black); 
jpanedisplay.setViewportView(table1);           
jpanedisplay.getViewport().setBackground(Color.white);
jpanedisplay.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black));

...

while(rs.next()){
     Vector<Object> rowVector = new Vector<Object>();
     for(int i=1;i<=columnCount;i++){
         rowVector.add(rs.getString(i));
            //System.out.print(rs.getString(i));
     }
     model.addRow(rowVector);

     // DON'T CALL Thread.sleep();
}
```

---

**UPDATE**

If you dont want the table added until the database task is finished, just use a method

```
private JTable createTable(ResultSet rs) {
    DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(columnNames, 0);
    JTable table = new JTable(model);

    table.setEnabled(false);
    JTableHeader header1 = table.getTableHeader();
    header1.setResizingAllowed(false);
    header1.setReorderingAllowed(false);
    header1.setForeground(Color.white);
    header1.setBackground(Color.black);

    while(rs.next()){
        Vector<Object> rowVector = new Vector<Object>();
        for(int i=1;i<=columnCount;i++){
            rowVector.add(rs.getString(i));

        }
        model.addRow(rowVector);
    }

    return table;
}
```

Then you can just add it to what ever panel

```
panel.add(new JScrollPane(createTable(rs));
```

---

## UPDATE #2

after Op explained that they were trying to get a dynamic look the rows being added, instead of all at One time.

I used a `java.swing.Timer` to add the rows.

[image]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.Timer;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

public class TestTimerTable {

    String[] cols = {"ID", "Name", "Country Code", "District", "Population"};
    DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(cols, 0);
    JTable table = new JTable(model);
    ResultSet rs = null;
    JButton start = new JButton("Start");
    Timer timer = new Timer(0, null);

    public TestTimerTable() {
        initDB();

        JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(table);
        scroll.setViewportView(table);

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test Timer Table");
        frame.add(scroll);
        frame.add(start, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);

        timer = new Timer(200, new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                try {
                    if (rs.next()) {
                        String s1 = rs.getString(1);
                        String s2 = rs.getString(2);
                        String s3 = rs.getString(3);
                        String s4 = rs.getString(4);
                        String s5 = rs.getString(5);
                        model.addRow(new Object[]{s1, s2, s3, s4, s5});
                    } else {
                        ((Timer) e.getSource()).stop();
                    }
                } catch (SQLException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
        start.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                timer.start();
            }
        });
    }

    private void initDB() {
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(
                    "jdbc:mysql://localhost/...", "...", "...");
            PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT *  FROM city");
            rs = ps.executeQuery();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new TestTimerTable();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok when then add the table to the panel _after_ the loop

Comment: Also just a note, for long running tasks, you should look into using a background thread like SwingWorker. Long database querying tasks should be done this way.

Comment: Did you even try this way?

Comment: the JTable is not displaying after adding each row . but it is displaying only when all row are added

Comment: Then use a `Swing Timer`.

Comment: perfect , but i dont want to use any button to add row , it there any way?

Comment: just do `timer.start()` at the very end of the `timer` code block;

Comment: if (rs.next()) {
                        String s1 = rs.getString(1);
                        String s2 = rs.getString(2);
                        String s3 = rs.getString(3);
                        String s4 = rs.getString(4);
                        String s5 = rs.getString(5);
                        model.addRow(new Object[]{s1, s2, s3, s4, s5});

This is static , i want this part to be dynamic , i have add a Vector , but giving me error "The final local variable rowVector cannot be assigned, since it is defined in an enclosing type"